# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection while trying to make JDBC connection to Oracle DB

Tags: jdbc

Im trying to make a JDBC connection to my Oracle DB. 
It works fine through TOAD but when im trying to establish the connection through JDBC it gives me the below error
"IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"
The syntax of the url and details provided in the url is correctly picked up from TNS file.
when I ping the hostname it connects but with telnet it gives me error
"Could not open connection to the host,on port 1521:Connect failed"

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Network Adapter could not establish the connection when connecting with Oracle DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834157/the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-when-connecting-with-orac)

Comment: I tried the mentioned resolutions but could not get help for the same

Answer (score 1):

Possible issues will be.

(a) Check if the database is up. Most of the times, database will not be up causing this issue. 
(b) Check if you are able to connect using sqlplus