# Failed to connect to Oracle database from Linux

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle RAC set up and trying to perform a database connection. When I am trying to connect from the sql developer or windows system, it is getting connected successfully. However, when I am trying to connect from my linux server(s), it is failing with different sql state and error codes.

I am using the below Java code to establish the connection.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr,"username","password");
```

When trying from the server 1, I am getting the below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

with `sqlstate 61000 and vendorcode 20.`

Server details are as below:

```
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
Release:        5.4
```

When trying from the server 2, I am getting the same error message with
`sqlstate 08006 and vendorcode 17002.`

Server details are as below:

```
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)
Release:        6.0
```

I googled about these error code and the reason but did not get any convincing solution.

Below are my doubts:

1. I did not understand why the error codes are different in the
   servers when I am running the same piece of code in both the
   servers.
2. What could be the possible reason of getting two different error codes with the same code and same database details.

Comment: Are you using the same OJDBC driver on both machines?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834157/the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-when-connecting-with-orac

Comment: what about tnsname? try to `tnsping` your server

Comment: stealing a relevant answer from the post I linked:

I would suggest you add the database IP name and IP resolution to the /etc/hosts.

I have the same error and when we do the above, it works fine.

Comment: @ user2879041 Thanks for the response. Could you please tell me how it is going to help.

Comment: @ Jorge Campos Yes, the same ojdbc jar is being used in both the servers.

Comment: What is your connection string?  Have you considered using Oracle's ezconnect?